# Recommended file formats and graphics libraries for importing 3D model into OpenGL/C++ project?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, file-format

If you wanted to:

- model an object in a 3D editor, e.g. Blender, Maya, etc
- export the model into a data/file format
- import the model into an project using OpenGL and C/C++

Then:

- What file format would you recommend exporting to, i.e. in terms of simplicity, portability, and compatibility (i.e. common/popular)?
- What graphics libraries would you recommend using to import the model into your OpenGL C/C++ project (i.e. preferably open source)?
- Additionally, are there data/file formats that also capture animation, i.e. an "animated model" format, such that the animation could be modeled in the 3D editor and somehow invoked inside the code (e.g. accessibility to frames in the animation sequence or some other paradigm for saving/loading details related to changes over time)?

Generally speaking, I'm seeking simplicity as the priority, i.e. help to get started with combining my backgrounds in both art and computer science. I am a computer science major at UMass while at the same time, sort of a "pseudo" double-major in art by taking electives in graphic design at my university as well as classes at the Art Institute of Boston during summer/winter sessions So, in other words, I am not a complete newbie, but at the same time I don't really want options that are so overloaded with crazy advanced configurations making it too difficult to get started with a basic demonstration project; i.e. as a first step to understanding how to bridge the gap between these two worlds, e.g. creating a program featuring a 3D character that the user can interact with.

Answer (score 17):

**[COLLADA](https://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/COLLADA_-_Digital_Asset_and_FX_Exchange_Schema)** (I'm saying it with a "ah" at the end), and [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) (ple as that).

And so, why COLLADA? Simple:

- COLLADA is an open standard made by Khronos (Sony specifically). The beauty of an open standard format is that it's, well, a standard! You can be assured that any output of a standard-conformant product would also read correctly by another standard-conformant product. Sad to say though, some 3d modelling products aren't that particular in their measures for standards conformance for COLLADA. But still be rest assured: Blender, Maya, 3ds Max and all the other big names in 3d modelling has good support for the format.
- COLLADA uses XML. This makes it much more simpler for you if your planning to create your own reader or writer.
- **ADDITIONAL:** COLLADA is, I think, the only format that is not tied to a specific company. This is a very good thing for us, you know.
- **ADDITIONAL 2:** It is known that COLLADA is slow to be parsed. That's true. But think of it: all other non-binary formats (like fbx) have also the same issues. For your needs, COLLADA should suffice.
- **ADDITIONAL 3:** COLLADA supports animations!

For the importer library, I highly recommend Assimp. Why?

- Assimp has support for any popular format you can imagine. It has a unified interface for all formats so that switching to another format is less of a pain.
- Assimp is extensible. You can thus import your proprietary format and still not modify your code.
- **ADDITIONAL 4:** Assimp is **open source**! Let's support open source software!

Comment: Collada is slow to parse , especially for complex models ;)

Comment: @MichaelIV Absolutely true. But for his purpose, COLLADA is more than he could ever ask for.

Comment: So in this case he also can use 3Ds and use lib3ds. Fast and simple.Collada is kind of old school ;)

Comment: I think you are wrong on this : "non-binary formats (like fbx)" FBX IS BINARY! :))

Comment: @MichaelIV See: http://download.autodesk.com/us/fbx/20112/FBX_SDK_HELP/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ff-150b16da11960d83164-6c6f.htm,topicNumber=d0e294

Comment: @MichaelIV Though there is a binary version, most fbx files now are stored in ASCII.

Comment: "FBX files (.fbx) are normally saved in a binary (or native) format, but they can also be saved in ASCII format" .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20224/discussion-between-michael-iv-and-mark-garcia)

Comment: Thank you for the input. Collada and Assimp definitely sounds good for my purposes. I'll also check out 3Ds and use lib3ds. It seems that part of the ongoing discussion on FBX is missing, so I'm not sure what to make of that. If you resolve your debate, please come back and share your conclusions! :)

Comment: I started out with FBX and ended up mostly using collada. FBX is definitely nice, but somewhat overkill for my use. What I love about collada is that I can easily LOOK at the data to make sure everything is set up correctly. As with FBX, collada files are pretty huge, so I have a simple converter to a custom binary format.

Comment: I guess my conclusion is : Collada = Really quick to implement. It's just traversing XML with colladadom. FBX = Takes a bit more time to get into, but features/support is much wider. Ideally you create a simple custom binary format that is fast and easy to load. FBX, collada and whatnot is just the just an intermediate step, so changing the intermediate format is just about writing a different exporter.

Answer (score 6):

First , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776408/whats-a-good-c-library-for-loading-models-for-use-in-opengl)  you can read about suggested model loading lbs.Lib [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) is really good and supports many formats.For the preferred formats.Collada-I wouldn't recommend because that is XML (text) based formats which is slow to parse. Obj format is also widespread but suffers from the same problems as Collada.It is still good if you want to write your own parser as its structure is very simple.But Instead I would suggest 3Ds which is binary.It doesn't support animations though.The most popular format today which supports both static mesh and animation is FBX.You can [download for free](http://usa.autodesk.com/fbx/) FBX SDK from Autodesk and connect it to your engine.The reason I would choose FBX is because both SDK and the format are really robust.For example ,in FBX you can embed not just geometry and animation but also scene objects as lights ,cameras etc.Autodesk docs are very nice too.
Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for the FBX recommendation. I have used it at work and other game studios use it too. The SDK is nice and supports many things.

Comment: You make a good case for FBX. I'll definitely explore FBX SDK and Assimp. Also, thanks for pointing out that other stackoverflow post. Very useful. :)

Answer (score 4):

I would reccomend using your own custom format that basically just a binary dump of the vertex buffer and index buffers used in your program. (Using d3d terms there, I know opengl has the same concepts but can't remember if they have different names).

I would then write a separate program using assimp that takes pretty much any format and writes out the file in your custom format. Then you can use collada or whatver to store your actual models in, but not have the complixity and slowness of loading that format at run time.

Comment: Maybe that's something to explore in the future if it makes practical sense to do so. Been down that path before, i.e. used to think that building my own libraries was the best solution for "everything", but mostly its not worth "reinventing the wheel" unless you're doing it for a practical purpose, i.e. making some improvement on existing solutions, and of course it helps to have some sort of experience with existing solutions to inform your decisions in designing an improved version. These days I subscribe to Pareto's principle, i.e. 80-20% rule, rather than get caught up in perfectionism.