# How to import 3d character with animation in mac application.

Tags: objective-c, macos, animation, 3d, maya

I created a 3d model with some animations in maya. I want to use it my mac application. One way I know is to export as dae file and use this. But most of time my dae file is not being exported and i get warnings as "null not supported by collada". is there any other way to use these models in app or how can I fix this error while exporting .dae file.

Comment: Which DAE exporter? There are several -- some are bad and the rest are terrible :(

You may have slightly more luck using FBX. There is a version of the FBX sdk for OSX: http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=10775847

Comment: I am using maya 2014 and exporting dae from the plugin that is installed with it.

Comment: This page http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/FBX-Plug-ins-Import-Export/FBX-2009-3-Problem-in-exporting-to-DAE-Autodesk-Collada/td-p/4045058 seems to suggest that the null warning happens if you have your skinned mesh grouped to your skeleton

Comment: I figured out same. But as I was using someone else's model so instead  of working on grouped mesh, I just changed the way to use 3d model in to my application. As my animations were quite simple so instead of exporting dae, I rendered png sequences for animations and used in the app.

Answer (score 0):

first of all it seems like something is wrong with your model if you can't export it. 
Also please add some information about the app which should then import the model. Probably you think about the SceneKit which already supports the Collada file format. 
 But there exist other libraries to which can be used for other formats. Take a look here: [Recommended file formats and graphics libraries for importing 3D model into OpenGL/C++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600158/recommended-file-formats-and-graphics-libraries-for-importing-3d-model-into-open) and here: http://assimp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yes, I am already using sceneKit, beacuse using dae with sceneKit is quite simple. I havnt tried the Assimp yet.